# getting the paths of a tree in a a dictionary with a true,false values according to which path i took

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tree, decision-tree

So i have a tree in python where i want to take each route until the leaf, and put each route alone in a dictionary where next to each node i put"true" if i went right, and "false" if i went left.

```
               cough
          true/       \ false
        fever           healthy
   true/     \ false
 influenza   cold
```

like according to this tree, i want to get this for an example {cough:true,fever:true}
and all the other paths.
i tried using recursion where in each iteration i give it the right and left child, but when i do that i get all the nodes and paths in the same dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: See my definition of a similar tree [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054927/6779307).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Checking paths to leaf in binary tree python giving data in the leaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054654/python-checking-paths-to-leaf-in-binary-tree-python-giving-data-in-the-leaf)

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: How is the tree stored in python?

Comment: update : instead of the dictionary i used a list and got and by recursion it got solved